# On the derivative of the Bernstein polynomial

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, polynomials

$\newcommand\Z{\Bbb Z}\newcommand\De{\Delta}$For a natural $n$ and a function $g\colon\Z\to\Bbb R$, let $B_n g$ be the corresponding Bernstein polynomial, so that
$$(B_n g)(x)=\sum_{k\in\Z} g(k)\binom nk x^k(1-x)^{n-k};$$
of course, $\binom nk=0$ unless $k\in\{0,\dots,n\}$.

It is easy to check (see e.g. [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/353868/36721) or [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/467048/36721)) that
$$(B_n g)'=nB_{n-1}\De g, \tag{1}\label{1}$$
where $(\De g)(k):=g(k+1)-g(k)$.

Has \eqref{1} appeared in a publication?

Comment: It's listed here as a basic property, so it would seem safe to assume that  it must have been mentioned in many papers also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial#Properties

Comment: @ChristianRemling : I don't see this there.

Comment: It's item #7 of the list: "the derivative can be written ..."

Comment: @ChristianRemling : Yes, I saw that, but that listed property is a property only of the basic Bernstein polynomials. Of course, as was said in my post, it is easy to prove (1) (with or without mentioning basic Bernstein polynomials), but the question is about (1), not about related properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's equation (2.1.9) of [Generalized Bernstein Polynomials](https://www.final.edu.tr/docs/10118972894pdf[1546613790].pdf) by Ceren Ustaoğlu (2014). Note that the stepsize is chosen as $1/n$, so

[image]
[image]

Ustaoğlu cites a source: George M. Phillips, [Interpolation and Approximation by Polynomials](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/0-387-21682-0_7) (2003), where it is theorem 7.12:

[image]

There may well be older references, which I have not searched for.

Answer (score 5):

I may be wrong, but it seems to me that $(B_n g)$ is a 1D Bézier curve. If you write $P_k$ instead of $g(k)$, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Derivative) show its derivative.

Update in response to comment: *Bézier curves* is a standard topic in Computer Graphics. Any search for it will turn up many textbooks. One of the classic/oldish ones is

> Farin, Gerald (1997). *Curves and surfaces for computer-aided geometric design* (4 ed.). Elsevier Science & Technology Books. ISBN 978-0-12-249054-5.

I think your formula (1) is Farin's (4.17) on page 49 of that book, but you will have to recheck the notation and definitions to be certain.

If you want "original references", that might be the works of Bézier and de Casteljau.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (upvoted). However, I asked for a reference to a publication.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Added reference.

Comment: Thank you for the added reference.